# Advantages to upgrading from SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: 2010, upgrade, edition

I feel like this should be extremely obvious, but after staring at [this](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx) document from Microsoft and Googling for a while I'm still at a loss as to the advantages of SharePoint Server 2010 and SharePoint Enterprise 2010 over SharePoint Foundation 2010.

My users currently use SharePoint Foundation 2010 to collaborate on a handful of excel documents within the office. There is talk of expanding to have a second and third SharePoint server at another plant and at our corporate offices.

If there is a reason to upgrade now would be a good time to ask for the money while we're talking expansion. Is it worth it from either an administrative or an end-user perspective? Or is the free version really just that wonderful?

Answer (score 2):

There's a good thread for a [similar question on SharePointOverflow.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/640/sharepoint-2010-foundation-vs-server), which is, by the way, a great place for questions like this and upgrading soon to StackExchange 2.0.

Since you mention Excel, you may be interested in a feature called Excel Services which extends the usefullness of Excel in SharePoint. If your users have a need to publish their Excel spreadsheets to a group, you may want to upgrade to Enterprise for that feature and a lot more.

More generally, an appealing set of features in Server and above is around social. People Search and My Sites are both added at that level. My Sites are an area for profiles. People Search helps navigate those profiles. In addition, results from collegues defined on your My Site will rank higher in Search.

As to the timing, the free version is wonderful, but if use is growing now may be the time to upgrade if you see your users benefitting from features above or linked to from SharePointOverflow. I think you might.